# SQL Server 2008 - Multiply 2 columns in SQL is not working

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am using a subquery to get column value and then multiply it with another column. but it gives error. Query is:

```
select 
    TotalCost, CurrencyType, b.TrxCurrency, 
    (select Rate 
     from CurrencyConversion 
     where FCurrencyType = a.CurrencyType 
       and TCurrencyType = b.TrxCurrency 
       and IsDelete = 0) as Rate,
    (TotalCost * Rate) as NewRate  
from 
    TB_Accom a 
inner join 
    Agency b on a.AgencySysId = b.AgencySysId
where  
    b.AgencySysId = 62 
    and TotalCost != 0
```

And the error I get is:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Invalid column name 'Rate'

Comment: Please post the structure or the DDL code for tables `CurrencyConversion`, `TB_Accom` and `Agency`

Comment: The error is saying that it cannot find a column called "Rate" in CurrencyConversion. Double check your column names - there may be a space in the name or something, and you may need [ ] around the column name.

Comment: Rate Column is exist in table but at the time of execution it gives error at alias "Rate" when I am replacing rate in TotalCost * Rate with Subquery. Then its working fine.